# ¿Como silenciar los errores de PHP?

Tags: php, php7, html2pdf

Estaba probando HTML2PDF, una "tontería" que solo tiene un archivo más el **composer.json** . Muestro mis códigos.

**print_pdf.php:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML('<h1> Hola mundo!! desde html2pdf </h1>');

$html2pdf->output();


?>
```

**composer.json:**

```
{    
    "require": {
        "spipu/html2pdf": "5.*"
    }
}
```

Y me daba el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML2Pdf\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php:2950 
    Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML2Pdf\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php(7653): TCPDF->Error('Some data has a...') 
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML2Pdf\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php(575): TCPDF->Output('document.pdf', 'I') 
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML2Pdf\print_pdf.php(11): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML2Pdf\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 2950
```

Me puse a investigar y leí que el problema, podría ser que hubiera un espacio antes del `<?php` inicial. Y sinceramente, me parecía algo raro que eso pudiera ser la razón, pero saqué el espacio(espacios en realidad) y solucionado el problema. Me aparecía el PDF de forma correcta.

De ahí viene mi duda, en lo que leí decían que tenía que silenciar lo siguiente:

***error_reporting(0) y ini_set('display_errors', 0)***

***¿Es recomendable o es mala idea silenciar esos errores?***

***En caso que sea recomendable ¿Como se silencian?***

Solo para aclarar, en dónde leí eso no explicaba cómo silenciarlos.
Y yo pregunto, porque cuando programo y empiezo un archivo, quizás es mala maña, mala costumbre mía pero empiezo a escribir los códigos desde la línea 5 aproximadamente.
Si me dicen que no es recomendable, no hay drama. Me acostumbraré a escribir desde la línea 1 o al menos en PHP.

Comment: No es recomendable ya que así no te va a alertar el lenguaje cuando algo falle

Comment: @Aprendiz Ah que cagada! Tendré que eliminar esa mala costumbre nomás. Muchas gracias por responder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Respondiendo a la primera pregunta:** No, no es recomendable en absoluto desactivar los errores debido a que siempre existe la posibilidad del error humano de cometer un error de código.
**Respondiendo a la segunda pregunta:** Si aun así deseas hacerlo, esta es la forma de configurar `error_reporting()`

```
 <?php

// Desactivar toda notificación de error
error_reporting(0);

// Notificar solamente errores de ejecución
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Notificar E_NOTICE también puede ser bueno (para informar de variables
// no inicializadas o capturar errores en nombres de variables ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Notificar todos los errores excepto E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Notificar todos los errores de PHP 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Notificar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(-1);

// Lo mismo que error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Fuente: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Una consulta, para saber nomas, eso tendría que estar dentro del archivo **print_pdf.php**?

Comment: "no es recomendable en absoluto desactivar los errores". No estoy de acuerdo con esta frase. Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que para el desarrollo es interesante poder ver los errores; pero el código que sube a producción en general no debería mostrar errores, trazas, mensajes de debug, etc. Los errores deberían mostrarse en forma de trazas en un fichero invisible al usuario, en lugar de mostrárselos en la interfaz gráfica, ya que este usuario no va a poder hacer nada con esa información.

Answer (score 2):

Ponte en una perspectiva de Usuario de tu sistema. Estás navegando por la aplicación y de pronto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: TCPDF ERROR: ......
```

Al usuario no le interesa el error (y muy probable que ni lo entienda), por lo que no le añade ningún valor y de hecho puede brindar información a algún atacante.

Volviendo a tu pregunta **¿Es recomendable o es mala idea silenciar esos errores?**, desde mi punto de vista sí es recomendable ocultar los errores de la vista, pero no obviarlos. Los `Fatal error` deben ser corregidos **SIEMPRE**, una forma de seguir viendo si tu aplicación produce errores y corregirlos sin afectar la salida, es estar pendiente del log, por ejemplo, en una consola linux con el comando:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log
```

Puedes estar pendiente de todo lo que genere tu aplicación, incluso cuando esta ya esté en producción.

Por cierto, el error que te sale ahí es porque antes de generar el PDF tu script está generando alguna salida (algún caracter perdido o un espacio).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Vlady, por los consejos y por el hacerme verlo desde otra vista! Es verdad que al usuario no le interesaria, simplemente le interesa que funcione.

Answer (score 2):

Hay que tener en cuenta el entorno:

- Desarrollo: **Nunca los errores siempre deben ser corregidos**
- Testing: **Nunca los errores deben ser corregidos**
- Producción: **Siempre se deben esconder** los errores y tratarlos desde el log

Mi recomendación a la hora de configurar los errores es hacerlo directamente a nivel de servidor modificando la directiva **error_reporting**, en lugar de hacerlo en tiempo de ejecución, ya que el servidor de desarrollo y producción no son los mismos podemos establecer un valor diferente para cada entorno. Esto previene que se nos olvide cambiar la directiva en tiempo de ejecución antes de subir a producción algún cambio.

Documentación: [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)